# How to structure a python phantomjs project for deployment to heroku

Tags: python, git, selenium, heroku, phantomjs

I'm trying to setup a testing project using python/selenium and phantomjs.

locally in windows I have the python part of my project in a virtualenv:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\phantomjs.exe")
```

It should be no problem to push this via git to heroku , probably changing the second line to :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

But is it possible to push an executable of phantomjs to the same heroku application and access it via selenium. If so how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use heroku buildpacks to push binaries to your apps.

I new to heroku too.

I manage to push this repo https://github.com/leesei/heroku-casper-node to heroku (It contains node, phantomjs, casperjs, and you can add python buildpack to it) and you may need to add phantomjs to environment path (What I see the buildpacks seems to do this already)